# Loading module to a templated page

Tags: php, php5

I am trying to create a web app (CMS) as part of my research project, and I use the code below to load modules into a page.  Please review this code.

```
public function LoadModule($module,$position){

    if(file_exists('modules/'.$module.'.tpl'))
    {
        //todo: might have to get a better thing for this !
        $mod = 'modules/'.$module.'.tpl';
        ob_start();
        include($mod);
        $mod = ob_get_clean();

        $this->html = str_replace('__{'.$position.'}__', $mod ,$this->html); 
    }
    else{
        if(function_exists('LOGIT')){

            LOGIT('$module - module not found.');
        }
        else {
            $this->html = str_replace('__{'.$position.'}__', "$module Modlule not found" ,$this->html);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it's a paste-issue, but you should intent your code ;)

You are building the file-path twice. You should move that line:

```
$mod = 'modules/'.$module.'.tpl';
```

To the begining of the function (and give it a better name):

```
public function LoadModule($module,$position)
{

    $absTemplatePath = 'modules/'.$module.'.tpl';
    if(file_exists($absTemplatePath ))
    {
```

That Line:

```
LOGIT('$module - module not found.');
```

should be (else `$module` wouldn't get replaced):

```
LOGIT("$module - module not found");
```

If the template file does not include php-code you should use `file_get_contents` instead of `ob_start, include, ob_get_clean` (performance-wise). If you do have php-code in your templates, you might have a look at zend-framework's Zend_View.